# Read txt file data into javascript array

Tags: javascript

I got a script that puts urls into one iframe by order:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){   
    var array = ['http://www.example1.come', 'http://www.example2.com', 'http://www.example3.com'];
    var beforeLoad = (new Date()).getTime();
    var loadTimes = [];
    $('#1').on('load', function() {
       loadTimes.push((new Date()).getTime());                  
       $('#1').attr('src', array.pop());
        if (array.length === 0) { 
            $.each(loadTimes, function(index, value) {
               $("#loadingtime"+index).html(value - beforeLoad); 
            });
        }
    }).attr('src', array.pop());
    });
    </script>
```

I got a txt file with a list of urls. The urls in that file are written in a column (1 column, each url starfs from new line). How can i replace the 'var array' in the javascript with the content of that txt file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the basic gist, you'll want to embed any code that you want to run after the file is retrieved where I placed the comment.

```
$.get("your_url", 
       function(data) {
           var array = data.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/) //regex to split on line ending
           var beforeLoad = (new Date()).getTime();
           var loadTimes = [];
           //.... rest of your code here
       }
);
```

Note that this doesn't do any error handling if the file isn't there, and you may want to rewrite it to use [jQuery's "Promise" interface described here.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/#jqxhr-object)

Comment: +1 for accounting for all the different possible line endings.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's get method to request the file directly from the server, or use get to call a php script that parses the file into a friendly format such as JSON.

```
$.get('file.txt');
```

If you parse the url's into JSON format, then when it is received you can easily use the urls.

```
$.get('file.txt', function(data){
    obj = JSON.parse(data);
    // ....
});
```